# How to disable console logging for the QuickBlox JS SDK?

Tags: quickblox

I am using:

> QuickBlox JavaScript SDK - v1.13.1 - 2015-09-18

I have tried the following, as described in [the docs](http://quickblox.com/developers/Javascript#Configuration):

```
var QB_CONFIG = {
    ssl: true,
    debug: {mode: 0},
};

myQB.init(QB_APPLICATION_ID, QB_AUTHORIZATION_KEY, QB_AUTHORIZATION_SECRET, QB_CONFIG);
```

Also:

```
var QB_CONFIG = {
    ssl: true,
    debug: false,
};
```

Without success:

```
[QBChat]: Status.CONNECTING
[QBChat]: Chat Protocol - WebSocket ...
```

Comment: We checked it with 1.15.1 version and it works. What is myQB?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var QB_CONFIG = {
    ssl: true,
    debug: {
              mode: 0,
              file: null
          }
};
```

Comment: if you satisfy with my ans then make it correct and vote up